# How to Create a Plugin for Elementor to Add Custom Color Option with a Single Input

Tags: wordpress, elementor

I want to create a custom WordPress plugin that can be used with Elementor. This plugin should allow users to easily add a custom color option to the elements they create using a single input.

I have already started with some initial steps, but I need further guidance on how to integrate this custom color option with the Elementor editor and how to save the selected color value to the WordPress database.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. How can I integrate the custom color option into the Elementor editor so that users can easily choose a color?
2. What steps do I need to take to save the color value selected by the user to the WordPress database?
3. Are there any plugins or other resources that can assist in this process?

I would greatly appreciate any help and further guidance on how to achieve this goal. Thank you!

---

Make sure to tailor this question to your specific needs and the progress you've made in your project. The more detailed and clear your question is, the better the chances of receiving helpful answers on Stack Overflow or other development forums.